# PHP to jquery dialog() interaction issues.

Tags: php, jquery, html, flash, jquery-dialog

I have an html button:

```
<button id="monitor" onclick="startMonitor('<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]; ?>', '<?php echo $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]; ?>', '<?php echo $camera_quality_flash; ?>');">Monitor</button>
```

This would load flash content:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var js = jQuery.noConflict();

var startMonitor = function(cameraHash, cameraName, cameraFlashQuality) {
var url = ['flash/app.php?user=<?php echo $id_hash; ?>', 'camera=' + cameraHash, 'name=' + encodeURIComponent(cameraName), 'quality=' + cameraFlashQuality].join('&');
js('<div></div>').load(url, function() {
    js(this).dialog();
});
};
```

I want to use the jquery dialog to open this content.  Everything passed in seems to be perfect (according to the GET response from firebug) but I still get a jquery error.

`missing ; before statement jquery.js line 612`

What am I doing wrong?  I'm not even sure how to debug this. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Firebug reports the GET as: `http://myurl.com/flash/app.php?user=dee8c751cfdd2b5fb8194a3a9bac12044621df3d&camera=8f753c6bb3a8d9852a220abff0ed0d7686563007&name=test22&quality=0`. I expect these values.

If I paste this url into my browser the flash app starts in the browser as expected but not with the jquery dialog obviously.  Must be something wrong with my jquery code?

Comment: Well for starters, the error is on line 612, and what you've provided here doesn't have a line 612; what does the returned content really look like and what's at that line? Also, it's hard to tell here, but it doesn't really look like you're sanitizing all this content correctly before you use it in JavaScript code.

Comment: this is the line in jquery.js: `window[ "eval" ].call( window, data );`.  Not sure what you want to see with the returned content.  You want the dump of the server Response in firebug?

Comment: try changing js('<div></div>') to your target EX:$('#result').load(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Incorrect answer removed.)*

---

Edit:

Initially, I misinterpreted the `jquery.js` as a file you created, rather than the real jquery.  After testing out the code, I can see that the data that you are sending may be the problem.  Can you post a sample with the data for `$result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"]`, `$result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"]`,`$camera_quality_flash`, and `$id_hash`?  Also, what is the value for `url` that results?

---

Solution:

The button submits the form, and the page is reloading.  The dialog shows, but then the page is immediately reloaded, so it seems like there never was a dialog.  In order to prevent this behavior, the button's `click()` function has to return **false** (if no value is return, it is treated as a **true** result).

Notes on this solution:

1. Relies on the objects being in existence, so I moved everything inside a `ready()` event.
2. Assumes this one of many buttons inside a loop (because of the `$i` variable in the PHP code), so the data is in the attributes of the button.
3. Since there may be several buttons with the same functionality, it is generalized for multiples.
4. The jQuery load command (cf., http://api.jquery.com/load/ ) takes 3 paramenters:

   - the url
   - some data
   - a callback function for when the load returns (if you only provide 2 parameters, the second one is assumed to be the callback function).  The callback parameters are:

     - *responseText*, the HTML returned from the server
     - *textStatus*, a status message
     - *XMLHttpRequest*, the request interface, which can be used to see various info about the request (cf., http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)

The HTML test file:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <?php 
        $i = 0;
        $result_cameras = array(array("camera_hash" => "test1", "camera_name" => "test2"));
        $camera_quality_flash = 1;
        $id_hash = "hashish";

        echo '<button id="monitor1" class="monitor" camHash="' . $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"] . '" camName="' . $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"] . '" camQual="' . $camera_quality_flash . '" >Monitor 1</button>';
        echo '<button id="monitor2" class="monitor" camHash="' . $result_cameras[$i]["camera_hash"] . '-2" camName="' . $result_cameras[$i]["camera_name"] . '-2" camQual="' . $camera_quality_flash . '-2" >Monitor 2</button>';
    ?>
    <div class="tester">TEST DIV</div>
</form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var js = jQuery.noConflict();
    js(document).ready(function(){

        var monitor = js(".monitor");
        //alert(monitor[1]);

        monitor.each(
            function(i){ 
                js(this).click(
                    function(){
                        //alert(js(this).attr('camHash'));
                        startMonitor( 
                            js(this).attr('camHash'),
                            js(this).attr('camName'),
                            js(this).attr('camQual')
                        ); 
                        return false;
                    }
                );
            }
        );

        var startMonitor = function(cameraHash, cameraName, cameraFlashQuality) {

            var url = [
                    'flash/app.php?user=<?php echo $id_hash; ?>', 
                    'camera=' + cameraHash, 
                    'name=' + encodeURIComponent(cameraName), 
                    'quality=' + cameraFlashQuality
                ].join('&');

            js('<div>TEST DIV 2</div>').load(url
                , function(response, status, xhr) {
                    js('.tester').text( "<div>xhr: <br />"
                        + xhr.status + "<br />"
                        + xhr.statusText + "<br />"
                        + xhr.getAllResponseHeaders() + "<br />"
                        + xhr.responseText + "<br />"
                        + xhr.responseXML + "<br />"
                        + "</div>"
                    );
//                  js(this).dialog();
                }
            );
        };
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: What you are looking at in the original post is ALL of the jquery code.  There is nothing more to this.  I could start posting the php code that passes into this `startMonitor` function but I can see from the GET response in firebug that everything is passed in okay.  Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Really appreciate the effort. Same error.  I've adjusted as suggested. The url is perfect when I uncomment `alert(url)`.  But it seems I never get here: `alert(this.toString());`.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, so what is the HTML that gets returned from the URL?  If you do not want to paste that code, you can send it to my junk email: testdee@yahoo.com

Comment: `flash/app.php?user=dee8c751cfdd2b5fb8194a3a9bac12044621df3d&camera=8f753c6bb3a8d9852a220abff0ed0d7686563007&name=test22&quality=0` this obviously varies depending which monitor button they press.  But each time I paste this into a browser it works as expected.

Comment: That's not what I meant.  That is the URL that the client sends, but not what the server returns.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the return content you show is the actual content?
If so, it is not right because it contains PHP tags.

If however this is copied from your server-side code, can you please post the ACTUAL response you get from the server as this is most probably where your problem is.

Thanks